# Filter out our own types in Eclipse 'open type'?

Tags: eclipse

I'm wondering if there is a way to configure the Eclipse 'Open Type' search tool to separate the types defined in 'our own' source code (i.e. source code in the project) from types defined in libraries? I very often want to find a project-defined type, but it is drowned in a sea of types from the library.

One solution would be to have all of our types in the same package, using the source package filter; unfortunately that is not possible right now. And it's a bit difficult to turn it on and off, often you *do* want to search among all types.

EDIT. Yes global text search, but that is slower and a lot clumsier for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want to check preferences dialog: Java > Appearance > Type filters.
There you can set up filter for the types from external libraries.

Comment: That's the same as the "Type Filters..." available from the dialog itself, isn't it? I've considered that, and the problem is as stated in the question "And it's a bit difficult to turn it on and off, often you do want to search among all types"... maybe there is some way to turn it on/off easily? I'll try...

Comment: Ok tried. It's rather cumbersome to turn on and off: click popdown arrow, select "Type Filters...", click enable or disable all, click apply, click close. Five steps :(. And 'Apply' seems to not preview. Anyway, if that's the only way...

Comment: Well, I couldn't find the function what you want, however, how about use 'Open Resource' (Ctrl+Shift+R)? With 'Open Type' (Ctrl+Shift+T) you can find any resource (or type) quickly. 'Open Resource' seems to show the resource in your workspace.

Comment: Yes, but Open Resource is like a file name search, it does not show all types (nested classes, perhaps anonymous top-level classes might be interesting too, but I never write such). ('Open Type' can not find all resources, I think you mistyped?) Now, maybe I should just forget about nested classes, then Open Resource works (I often use it just to not see library types, btw).